# Variational analysis for Schrodinger bridges

Tags: integration, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier, divergence-operator, variational-analysis

I am working on variational analysis for the Schrodinger bridge problem (SBP), defined as follows.

The SBP is equivalent to seeking a flow $\rho(t, x)$ and a velocity field $v(t, x)$, that are a solution to the following constrained minimization problem:
\begin{align}
    \inf_{(\rho, v)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \int_{0}^{1} &\left[ \frac{1}{2} \lVert v(t,x) \rVert^{2} + \frac{\gamma^{2}}{8} \lVert \nabla \log{ \rho(t,x) } \rVert^{2} \right] \rho(t, x) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{d} x\\
    &\frac{ \partial \rho }{ \partial t } + \nabla \cdot (v \rho) = 0
\end{align}

The analysis starts by writing out the Lagrangian for the above problem, as:
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L}(\rho, v, \lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \lVert v(t,x) \rVert^{2} \rho(t,x) + \frac{\gamma^{2}}{8} \lVert \nabla \log{ \rho(t,x) } \rVert^{2}  \rho(t, x) + \underbrace{\lambda(t, x) \left( \frac{ \partial \rho }{ \partial t } + \nabla \cdot (v \rho) \right)}_{\Lambda} \right] \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{d} x 
\end{align*}

Then, the proof transforms the $\Lambda$ term, via integration by parts and assuming limits of $x \rightarrow \infty$. It shows that the above $\mathcal{L}$ is equivalent to the following expression:
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{L}(\rho, v, \lambda) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \int_{0}^{1} \left[ \frac{1}{2} \lVert v(t, x) \rVert^{2} + \frac{\gamma^{2}}{8} \lVert \nabla \log{ \rho(t, x) } \rVert^{2} + \left( -\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial t} - \nabla \lambda \cdot v  \right) \right]  \rho(t, x) \mathrm{d} t \mathrm{d} x + \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \left[ \lambda(1, x) \rho(1, x) - \lambda(0, x) \rho(0, x) \right] \mathrm{d} x
\end{align*}

I am uncertain about whether there is an equality here. I am confused how to transform from the first $\mathcal{L}$ to the second form. Can anyone help me show the derivation process?

Answer (score 1):

Since the total derivative of any scalar function $\lambda$ with respect to $t$ is:
$$
d_t\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})
=
\partial_t\lambda(t,\mathbf{x}) + \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{dt}\cdot\nabla\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})
=
\partial_t\lambda(t,\mathbf{x}) + v(t,\mathbf{x})\cdot\nabla\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})
$$

and $\nabla\cdot(\rho(t,\mathbf{x}) v(t,\mathbf{x})) = \rho(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x}) + v(t,\mathbf{x})\cdot\nabla\rho(t,\mathbf{x})$, you can rewrite your $\Lambda$ term as :
$$
\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\left(d_t\rho(t,\mathbf{x}) + \rho(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x})\right)
$$
where $v(t,\mathbf{x})$ is the same velocity field.

It is necessary to write the total derivative since you can not integrate in the following integration by parts the $\partial_t\rho(t,\mathbf{x})$ term, with the derivative being $\partial$ instead of $d$. The first symbol is called *partial* derivative, because it is a *partial* derivation relative to one variable.

The integration by parts gives :
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}\int_0^1dt\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\left(d_t\rho(t,\mathbf{x}) + \rho(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x})\right)
=
\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}[\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\rho(t,\mathbf{x})]_0^1
-
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}\int_0^1dt\rho(t,\mathbf{x})\left(d_t\lambda(t,\mathbf{x}) - \lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x})\right)
=
\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}[\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\rho(t,\mathbf{x})]_0^1
+
\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}\int_0^1dt\rho(t,\mathbf{x})(-\partial_t\lambda(t,\mathbf{x}) - v(t,\mathbf{x})\cdot\nabla\lambda(t,\mathbf{x}))
+ 
\\
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}\int_0^1dt\rho(t,\mathbf{x})\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x})
$$
As you can see for the last equality, the first and second lines are expected, but the third is not.
Therefore the equality between the two Lagrangians should hold if
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}d\mathbf{x}\int_0^1dt\lambda(t,\mathbf{x})\rho(t,\mathbf{x})\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x}) = 0
$$

Do you have any condition on the velocity field, such as incompressibility ($\nabla\cdot v(t,\mathbf{x}) = 0)$ ?

Details:

Comment: I have two questions. (1) What is the total derivative about? (2) Is your condition equivalent to $(\int dx) (\int dt) (\lambda \rho \nabla \cdot v) = 0$? That is, the two integrations are computed separately and then multiplied.

Comment: (1)The total derivative is the fancy name physicists use to call the "Chain Rule", that is for any function $f = f(x,y,z,t) = f(\mathbf{x},t)$, the total time derivative is obtain by partially differentiating with respect to time but you have additional terms : $d_tf = \partial_tf + \partial_xf d_tx + \partial_yf d_ty + ... = \partial_tf + \partial_xf v_x + ... = \partial_tf + v\cdot\nabla f $.
(2) I will edit later to add more details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation! Would you mind writing your answer in similar notations as my question text? It would be easier for my understanding. :)

Comment: I am a bit confused by the $v$ term in your total derivative expression. Is this the same $v$ as my $v(t, x)$? I don't see how the total derivative expression can be true for arbitrary $f$.

Comment: Your answer looks impressive! For terms that look like $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \mathrm{d} x \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \mathrm{d} t (...)$, do you really mean / are they equivalent to $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} (...) \mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d} t$

Comment: The original paper said that, assuming limits for $\lVert x \rVert \rightarrow \infty$ are zero, we can omit the last term. How does that hold?